# Community is inconsistent with account lists

Tags: support, area-51, profile-page, user-accounts, community-user

Here we see Community's list of accounts. She has 106 communities (does that exclude beta sites?) and has 1 rep on all of them.

[image]

But over at her [Network Profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=accounts), she only has one account, on Area 51:

[image]

I guess it is showing Area 51 because of the <s>strange</s> old code that Area 51 uses, but is is odd that she shows 106 accounts (when there are 138 sites officially) and that she only shows one on the Accounts tab...

Why is this, and should it be changed? Is it to do with the new user profile?

Update:

It's not because of the new profile, this is the image on Stack Overflow. Clicking `view more` ironically shows less.

[image]

Comment: The Community user [exists on Beta sites](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) too, by the way.

Comment: I know, I just wondered if it wasn't displaying them...